# Laravel get Id from the collection

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel get Id from the collection

```
$collection = Test::whereDate('created_at', '=', $today)->where('cuid', $user->id)->where('month', date('m'))->get();        
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($collection);
        echo "</pre>";
        exit();
```

How to return id from this collection

because i want to update for that particular id

Comment: loop through the collection and get the id as a attribute of object

Comment: this id is unique i think no need to loop

Comment: @Mytesting You don't but you should know that `$collection` returns an array.

Comment: @Mytesting see my answer, you will have an idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `user_id` is `unique`, use `first()` instead of `get()`

```
$collection = Test::whereDate('created_at', '=', $today)->where('cuid', $user->id)->where('month', date('m'))->first();
```

Then access `id` like

```
$id = $collection->id;
```

Otherwise you need to `loop` through collection array and access `id` from individual object.

Answer (score 1):

You can just update using that query without doing `get` at all:

```
Test::whereDate('created_at', '=', $today)
          ->where('cuid', $user->id)
          ->where('month', date('m'))
          ->update([
            'column' => 'columnValue' 
           ]);
```

By the way you claim that the id should be unique but I find that a bit hard to believe given this query so make sure you're absolutely 100% correct with this assumption.

Answer (score 0):

```
$collection = Test::whereDate('created_at', '=', $today)->where('cuid', $user->id)->where('month', date('m'))->pluck(['id']);        
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($collection);
        echo "</pre>";
        exit();
```

In this way you will only get ids of all values

Answer (score 0):

```
   Test::whereDate('created_at', '=', $today)->where('cuid', $user->id)->where('month', date('m'))->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

if you know it is unique :

```
   Test::whereDate('created_at', '=', $today)->where('cuid', $user->id)->where('month', date('m'))->first()->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using get()  which will return collection even if there is only one result. Either loop through them or replace get() with first()
Example: If you are trying to get single element.

```
$collection = Test::whereDate('created_at', '=', $today)->where('cuid', $user->id)->where('month', date('m'))->first();        
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($collection->id);
        echo "</pre>";
        exit();
```